# Почему не работает input в форме?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

Есть список товаров на `jsp` у каждого есть свой `id`. При при нажатии на кнопку `More` в сервлет должен приходить запрос с `id` товара. Но прихоит всегда зеачение `1`.

```
<form method="get" action="get_all_proposes/get_propose_by_id">
    <c:forEach var="propose" items="${requestScope.allProposes}">

        <ul>

            <li>Model: <c:out value="${propose.model}"/></li>
            <li>Mark: <c:out value="${propose.mark}"/></li>
            <li>Sold: <c:out value="${propose.sold}"/></li>
            <input name="pId" type="number" value="${propose.id}">
            <input type="submit" value="More">
            <hr>

        </ul>

    </c:forEach>
</form>
```

На сервере это принимается так:

```
final int pId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("pId"));
```

Почему всегда приходит `1`? Как это исправить?

Comment: самый простой вариант - перенести тег формы внутрь цикла - для каждого товара будет своя форма и при сабмите будут отправлены данные отдельной формы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

допустим у вас есть три объекта

```
<ul>
    ...
    <input name="pId" type="number" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="More">
</ul>
<ul>
    ...
    <input name="pId" type="number" value="2">
    <input type="submit" value="More">
</ul>
<ul>
    ...
    <input name="pId" type="number" value="3">
    <input type="submit" value="More">
</ul>
```

И все это находится в одной форме! При нажатии любого из `submit` на сервер улетают значения всех `input`, то есть строка запроса будет выгляеть примерно так: `get_all_proposes/get_propose_by_id?pId=1&pId=2&pId=3`. На сервере вы, скорее всего, ловите только первый.
Я бы посоветовал вам исправить

```
<input type="submit" value="More">
```

на

```
<a href="get_all_proposes/get_propose_by_id?pId=${propose.id}">More</a>
```